# how to configure catch all mail in zpanel

Tags: centos, hosting-services

I have a CentOS configured with zpanel and I want to setup catch all mail but there is no option in zpanel to configure it.
I have tried to search with google but not find any working solution.

How can I set that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For configuring a catchall mail in zpanel you need to do some changes in the postfix database.

1. create a mail account in which you want to get bounce mails.
2. then login to your phpmyadmin with mysql root user then select postfix database.
3. after this you will see alias table select that table.
4. you will see your mailbox which you have created earlier copy that and change user@domain -> @domain and then save.
5. OK done now you will get un routed mail for your domain in your mailbox.